# How to get Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME") to work with GitHub Actions

Tags: r, github-actions

I'm setting up a job with macOS/R and i'm trying to set date format with:

```
- name: Set locale
        run: Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "pt_BR.UTF-8")
        shell: Rscript {0}
```

with no success. The script runs, but next job (a xaringan presentation) still builds with english date formats -- i'm talking about `format(Sys.Date(), '%d de %B de %Y')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run this in the same step as your other commands, because you get a new shell for every `run` element.